# Assign values of one matrix to another

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vector

I have created a vector `A` having six elements.

```
A=[10,20,40, 60,70,80]
```

Now, I want to create another vector `B` such that it has the same elements delayed by 2 index/sample values.

```
B=[0,0, 10,20, 40,60,70,80]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Simply concatenate the two in one array:

```matlab
A=[10,20,40, 60,70,80]
B = [0, 0, A]

% Or a bit more fancy and changeable:
delay = 2;  % Number of zeros to insert
B = [zeros(1, delay), A];  % Concatenate the two

% Or by direct indexing:
B(1, delay+1:delay+numel(A)) = A;
```